# from pymodbus.constants import Endian throws an error

Tags: python, pymodbus

I'm trying to learn and program using pyModbus.  I have an example program which is running fine.  It has this code to import the ModbusClient

```
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient
```

which works ok.

Now I'm trying to run and understand one the pyModbus website examples which has this code:

```
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
```

This one throws an error on the first line

> from pymodbus.constants import Endian  ImportError: No module name
>   pymodbus.constants

This is probably a naive user problem, as my experience with Python objects is weak.  But can you help?...RDK

Comment: Could you try re-installing or upgrading `pymodbus` in your environment? Then, restart your program and try again

Comment: I only yesterday installed the pyModbus from the git site (https://github.com/sourceperl/pyModbusTCP) on to my Pi 3 running Debian Stretch.  Trying to run on my Pi

Comment: I'm trying to run the "SunSpec client Example" (https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/sunspec_client.html) which fail on the import step

Comment: Sunspec client is outdated example and the git site you are referring Is not the official repo for pymodbus. Install the latest pymodbus with `pip install pymodbus -U` or clone it from the official repo `https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus` .For using `Endian` use `from pymodbus.payload import Endian`